# mod_rewrite `Redirect` how?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2, httpd.conf

I have 2 urls say `thinkingmonkey.me` and `thinkingmonkey.com` both have ip-address  127.0.0.1 (A.K.A localhost).

I want to redirect any requests to `thinkingmonkey.com` to `thinkingmonkey.me`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /mysite
    ServerName thinkingmonkey.me
    ServerAlias www.thinkingmonkey.me
    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ServerName thinkingmonkey.com

    Redirect thinkingmonkey.com  http://thinkingmonkey.me/

  #  Redirect / http://thinkingmonkey.me/ #have even tried this

    ServerAlias www.thinkingmonkey.com
    RewriteEngine on
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to access `thinkingmonkey.com` the url does not get redirected to `thinkingmonkey.me`. The url in the brower's address bar remains `thinkingmonkey.com`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_rewrite is considered better and more powerful to handle these rewrites. You can use following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)?thinkingmonkey\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1thinkingmonkey.me%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

If you really-really want to use mod_aias you can put this line in `VirtualHost` section of `thinkingmonkey.com`:

```
Redirect 301 / http://thinkingmonkey.me/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !.*thinkingmonkey\.me$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://thinkingmonkey.me/$1 [R]
```

The documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html